# Pivot Row Filter: set visible to false if pivotitem is unequal list of values

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

while writing a vba code to enable users to change a pivot table to certain criteria by a single click, I ran into a little problem. I hope someone has the solution or an idea for this.

I need to filter all acccounts of a list in order to have only consulting costs for example. I know that you basically have to "deselect" all the criteria/values that you don't want to see. The Problem is that there are so many account numbers that it would take ages to write down for every value `.PivotItems("90000000").Visible = False`. And I am sure that there is an elegant solution to that.

Is there a way to get something like `if PivotItem<> [several values with OR operator] Then Visible = False`?

In addition to that, there is another hurdle: Sometimes accounts don't have a value and thus are not shown in the balance list (rawdata/pivotsource). If I have now `PivotItem("x").Visible = False` and X does not exist, the sub runs into an error. Is there a way to bypass this situation, to ignore it, if a value does not exist?

Here's the setup:
The pivot basically contains a balance list, which has the period (month) in the column, the accounts and account description in the row and partner-ID in the pagefield.

The code so far is as follows

```
Sub Pivot_FS10N_consulting()
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("FS10N Pivot").Range("A8").clear

Set pvt = Sheets("FS10N Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
With pvt
    .ClearTable
    .AddDataField pvt.PivotFields("Value in local currency"), "Value", xlSum

        With .PivotFields("Partner-ID")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
            .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
            .PivotItems("246").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("247").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("457").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("631").Visible = False
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With

        With .PivotFields("Period")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With .PivotFields("Account")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1

            'Filter criteria should be here right now

        End With

        With .PivotFields("Account description")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With

    For Each pf In .PivotFields
    pf.Subtotals(1) = False
    Next pf

    .ColumnGrand = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    .TableStyle2 = "FS10N"
End With

With Sheets("FS10N Pivot").Range("A8")
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .Interior.Color = 1200359
    .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    .Value = "Consulting"
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT to clarify:** 
I need to select everything **unequal** a set or list of account numbers, to avoid the risk of keeping an account visible if it got created new in the ERP and I don't have it in the code. And I have the, maybe illusion to not check the numbers every month for validity.
Can I refer to a range of cells to check, if I copy the account numbers to another sheet or on the same sheet? Then it just has to check if the number is in there, and if it's not the case then the visibility should be set to false.

System Info:
OS: Windows 7
Excel 2007 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Store all the account numbers you want to keep in a scripting dictionary. Then loop through the .PivotItems and check if each one exists in the dictionary. If not, hide the item.

```
Sub test()

'this Dictionary will store the account numbers we want to NOT hide
Dim hideAccounts As Object
Set hideAccounts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'say, for example, the accounts you want to hide are on sheet one cells 1--20
'loop through the cells and add the accounts to the collection
With Sheets(1).Range("A1:A20")
    For i = 1 To .Count
        hideAccounts.Add .Cells(i),.Cells(i) 'adding to the dict in the format key, value
    Next i
End With

'
'...insert some code to create a pivot table
'
With myPivot
    for each itm in .PivotItems
        if not hideAccounts.Exists(itm) then 'if it does not exist in the dictionary
            .PivotItems(itm).visible=False'set it to invisible
        end if
    next

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention something, wasn't specific enough. I wanted to go the route to check everything unequal certain acccountnumbers since the other numbers change at times or there are new numbers, and I want to keep the maintaining as hasslefree as possible. Without checking each month, I run into the risk that the sum contains also an account that shouldn't have been selected.

Comment: so to clarify--my code is unchecking everything from a list. You want code that unchecks everything that is NOT in the list? If so--what OS are you on? Microsoft or Mac? (can be trickier on a mac)

Comment: yes indeed. Everything that is not on the list should be hidden. The OS is Windows. If it would help... I have enough space to take the different lists of account numbers and insert it either on the same sheet ( and hide them) or in a different sheet. If that helps.

Comment: and what kind of system are you running on? Microsoft? Have you used microsoft scripting dictionaries?

Comment: check out the edit above. I am on a mac so cannot test, but basically you add your 'good accounts' to a dictionary, then loop through the pivot items, check if they are a 'good account' using the .Exists property of the dict, then hide them if not.

Comment: first error I solved, the .PivotFields was missing. Now i get a 1004 runtimer error at `If Not hideAccounts.Exists(itm) Then`. I'll check that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I've written two posts on this kind of thing that also give you a much faster way to deselect large number of PivotItems without iteration.

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/12/03/inversely-filter-a-pivot-based-on-an-external-range/

Also note that there appears to be a bug whereby filtering Pivots that have slicers may be very very slow. See my post here:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/11/17/filtering-pivottables-with-vba-deselect-slicers-first/